# Windows Phone 8.1 how to display Progress Ring when Navigating to another Page?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Completely new to WinPhone8.1:

My WinPhone8.1 app seems to Navigate quite slowly between pages - each page is a question and I have Previous/Next buttons:

```
private void btnNextQuestion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressRing1.IsActive = true;
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Question), _survey.Id.ToString() + "|" + _nextField.Id.ToString());
    }
```

As you can see I simply tried to set `ProgressRing1.IsActive = true;` which I didn't expect to work, but I tried it anyway. I then tried to get clever and use a Task (which are also new to me - so maybe I've done it wrong) to start the ProgressRing but this didn't have any effect either:

```
private async void btnNextQuestion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => StartProgrssRing());
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Question), _survey.Id.ToString() + "|" + _nextField.Id.ToString());
    }

    private void StartProgrssRing()
    {
        ProgressRing1.IsActive = true;
    }
```

So Could anyone explain how I can achieve my aim - which is to basically let the user know that their button press has been recognised and the app is processing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let the UI thread run a bit to refresh the UI. There's many ways to reach this result, the one I'd suggest here is to call `Task.Delay`:

```
private async void btnNextQuestion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ProgressRing1.IsActive = true;

    // Wait 2 ms to let the UI thread execute
    await Task.Delay(2);

    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Question), _survey.Id.ToString() + "|" + _nextField.Id.ToString());
}
```

Why 2 ms? Because you need to give the UI thread at least 1.6 ms (the duration between each frame) so make sure the UI is refreshed. Otherwise, it may execute your call to `Frame.Navigate` without refreshing the UI.

Comment: Perfect! Works exactly as required. Thanks for the info.